# Find the K'th element of a list using foldr and function application ($) explanation

Tags: haskell

I'm currently at 6th chapter of Learn you a Haskell... Just recently started working my way on 99 questions.

The 3rd problem is to  find the K'th element of a list. I've implemented it using `take` and `zip`.

The problem I have is understanding the alternate solution offered:

```
elementAt''' xs n = head $ foldr ($) xs 
                     $ replicate (n - 1) tail
```

I'm "almost there" but I don't quite get it. I know the definition of the `$` but.. Can you please explain to me the order of the execution of the above code. Also, is this often used as a solution to various problems, is this idiomatic or just... acrobatic ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you expand the definition of `foldr`

```
foldr f z (x1:x2:x3:...:[]) = x1 `f` x2 `f` x3 `f`... `f` z
```

you see that `elementAt'''` becomes

```
elementAt''' xs n = head (tail $ tail $ ... $ tail $ xs)
```

(note: it should be `replicate n tail` instead of `replicate (n-1) tail` if indexing is 0-based).

So you apply `tail` to `xs` the appropriate number of times, which has the same result as `drop (n-1) xs` if `xs` is long enough, but raises an error if it's too short, and take the `head` of the resulting list (if `xs` is too short, that latter would also raise an error with `drop (n-1)`).

What it does is thus

- discard the first element of the list
- discard the first element of the resulting list (`n-1` times altogether)
- take the `head` of the resulting list

> Also, is this often used as a solution to various problems, is this idiomatic or just... acrobatic

In this case, just acrobatic. The `foldr` has to expand the full application before it can work back to the front taking the `tail`s, thus it's less efficient than the straightforward traversal.

Comment: I haven't considered last expression as a list of partially applied functions, it's much clearer now.

Answer (score 6):

Break it down into the two major steps. First, the function replicates `tail`
`(n-1)` times. So you end up with something like

```
elementAt''' xs n = head $ foldr ($) xs [tail, tail, tail, ..., tail]
```

Now, the definition of `foldr` on a list expands to something like this

```
foldr f x [y1, y2, y3, ..., yn] = (y1 `f` (y1 `f` (... (yn `f` x))) ...)
```

So, that fold will expand to (replace `f` with `$` and all the `y`s with `tail`)

```
foldr ($) xs [tail, tail, tail, ..., tail] 
= (tail $ (tail $ (tail $ ...  (tail xs))) ... )
{- Since $ is right associative anyway -}
= tail $ tail $ tail $ tail $ ... $ tail xs
```

where there are `(n-1)` calls to `tail` composed together. After taking `n-1`
tails, it just extracts the first element of the remaining list and gives that
back.

Another way to write it that makes the composition more explicit (in my opinion) would
be like this

```
elementAt n = head . (foldr (.) id $ replicate (n-1) tail)
```

Comment: when doing function composition we must use only functions so, **id** in this case acts as a place holder, it is composed further as a whole with **head** so the argument (list) that gets passed to the function actually gets passed to the id function, is that correct ? Is **id** used as a place-holder in these cases with foldr  ?

Comment: @durmitor: a slightly more mathematical way of looking at it is this: the type `a -> a` forms a monoid with function composition as the binary operation and `id :: a -> a` as the identity, because if `f, g, h :: a -> a`, then `f . (g . h) == (f . g) . h` and `f . id == id . f == f`.  So just like `foldr (+) 0` sums a list of numbers, returning `0` for the empty list, `foldr (.) id` composes a list of functions that share the same argument and result type, returning `id` (the function that "does nothing") for the empty list.